# how to jquery post in asmx?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, asmx, webforms

Im trying to get a response from a function in a webservice but i dont think i am creating the service correctly...

This is the code for web service...

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal ManufID As String) As String

        Return "{\'error\': \'Not found\'}"

    End Function

End Class
```

this is the jquery...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: '{' +
                    'ManufID:"' + item + '"' +
               '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = json_parse(msg.d);
            if (!data.error) {
                $.each(data, function (d) {
                    alert(data[d].model);
                    $("<option>").attr("value", data[d].id).text(data[d].model).appendTo($('.Finish1'));
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Cannot get memeber's notes data\n" + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert('Get Details Failure: ' + msg);
        }
    });
```

I know it wont work completely yet, im just trying to get the communication right for now...?thanks

Comment: Is it becoz i am returning a json object?

Comment: Are you calling this webservice from a page within the same application?

Comment: Your service class needs the ScriptService attribute on it or it will only return XML, and you shouldn't manually return a JSON string. ASP.NET will handle it automatically if you return a value or object: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article out. http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

If you only plan to call this from within your application, you should create a page method instead of a web service.

Throw this under your page_load() function of Default.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Then put this in the header of Default.aspx

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: i would love to do it like this, but i have to do it through the web service i am afraid

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why does it have to be a web service?

Comment: i duno but all ajax calls ive been told to place in this web service